# Check if string is encode or not with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encode

I got `&nbsp;` instead of space on my html textbox.
I am trying to check if string is encoded or not i.e. if it is a space or a `&nbsp;` How can I check if a string is a real string to `&nbsp;`

I tried this but no luck

```
Var isItaString = isEncoded(‘&nbsp;&nbsp’)
function isEncoded(str) {
    return typeof str == "string" && decodeURIComponent(str) !== str;
}
```

Comment: [&nbsp;](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) isn't a space and use [RegexOne - Learn Regular Expressions - Lesson 1: An Introduction, and the ABCs](https://www.regexone.com/) instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not text encoding but conversion to HTML Entities.

To check you should see if there is any presence of HTML entity. Here is complete list of such words:

```
["&nbsp","&iexcl","&cent","&pound","&curren","&yen","&brvbar","&sect","&uml","&copy","&ordf","&laquo","&not","&reg","&macr","&deg","&plusmn","&sup2","&sup3","&acute","&micro","&para","&middot","&cedil","&sup1","&ordm","&raquo","&frac14","&frac12","&frac34","&iquest","&Agrave","&Aacute","&Acirc","&Atilde","&Auml","&Aring","&AElig","&Ccedil","&Egrave","&Eacute","&Ecirc","&Euml","&Igrave","&Iacute","&Icirc","&Iuml","&ETH","&Ntilde","&Ograve","&Oacute","&Ocirc","&Otilde","&Ouml","&times","&Oslash","&Ugrave","&Uacute","&Ucirc","&Uuml","&Yacute","&THORN","&szlig","&agrave","&aacute","&acirc","&atilde","&auml","&aring","&aelig","&ccedil","&egrave","&eacute","&ecirc","&euml","&igrave","&iacute","&icirc","&iuml","&eth","&ntilde","&ograve","&oacute","&ocirc","&otilde","&ouml","&divide","&oslash","&ugrave","&uacute","&ucirc","&uuml","&yacute","&thorn","&yuml","&fnof","&Alpha","&Beta","&Gamma","&Delta","&Epsilon","&Zeta","&Eta","&Theta","&Iota","&Kappa","&Lambda","&Mu","&Nu","&Xi","&Omicron","&Pi","&Rho","&Sigma","&Tau","&Upsilon","&Phi","&Chi","&Psi","&Omega","&alpha","&beta","&gamma","&delta","&epsilon","&zeta","&eta","&theta","&iota","&kappa","&lambda","&mu","&nu","&xi","&omicron","&pi","&rho","&sigmaf","&sigma","&tau","&upsilon","&phi","&chi","&psi","&omega","&thetasym","&upsih","&piv","&bull","&hellip","&prime","&Prime","&oline","&frasl","&weierp","&image","&real","&trade","&alefsym","&larr","&uarr","&rarr","&darr","&harr","&crarr","&lArr","&uArr","&rArr","&dArr","&hArr","&forall","&part","&exist","&empty","&nabla","&isin","&notin","&ni","&prod","&sum","&minus","&lowast","&radic","&prop","&infin","&ang","&and","&or","&cap","&cup","&int","&there4","&sim","&cong","&asymp","&ne","&equiv","&le","&ge","&sub","&sup","&nsub","&sube","&supe","&oplus","&otimes","&perp","&sdot","&lceil","&rceil","&lfloor","&rfloor","&lang","&rang","&loz","&spades","&clubs","&hearts","&diams","&\"","&amp","&lt","&gt","&OElig","&oelig","&Scaron","&scaron","&Yuml","&circ","&tilde","&ndash","&mdash","&lsquo","&rsquo","&sbquo","&ldquo","&rdquo","&bdquo","&dagger","&Dagger","&permil","&lsaquo","&rsaquo","&euro"]
```

Do a regex search in the string and you will be good!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help from answers I figured out that they are html entities and need regex, replacement.

```
var decodeEntities = (function decodeEntities() {
            var element = document.createElement('div');

            function decodeHTMLEntities(str) {
                if (str && typeof str === 'string') {
                    str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
                    str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
                    element.innerHTML = str;
                    str = element.textContent;
                    element.textContent = '';
                }

                return str;
            }

            return decodeHTMLEntities;
        })();
```

It would be helpful to other if someone convert this code to a single function.